# Why all the elements of sylow subgroups are not adding up to the no. of elements of Group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Show that a group of order $70$ can not be simple.

I've tried to solve using Sylow theorem. I got $1, 5, 7, 35$ Sylow $2$-subgroups, $1$ sylow $5$-subgroup and $1$ sylow $7$-subgroup. Now the only choice is $35$ Sylow $2$-subgroups which would yield $36$ elements. Now we are left with $34$ elements but we have only one sylow $5$-subgroup and one sylow $7$-subgroup.

Why all the elements of sylow subgroups are not adding up to $70$?

Comment: Probably because your group might have elements of order 14 for example, which don't belong to any Sylow subgroup...

Comment: Probably there are elements of composite order.

Comment: BTW, you may want to edit your title. Your question seems to be about something connected with but not exactly about simpleness of groups.

Comment: you know that 70=2.5.7 so use this fact

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The elements in a Sylow subgroup have a prime power as order, if the group has an element of order 35 (for example) it wont be in a sylow subgroup.

The exercise is already solved since you know that there is only one 7-sylow, it has to be normal ([here is a proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems#Consequences)).